# Parse.com security Role not saving

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

This is my first time playing around with security roles in Parse and I believe what I'm trying to do is fairly simple. I want to create a new security Role after I signup a new user using the afterSave trigger in CloudCode.

I've verified that this is being called and the roleName is correct, but nothing is being saved in the data browser. I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic here for this not to be working - is there a setting somewhere I need to turn on?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
 var user = request.object;
 if (user.existed()) { return; }

 var acl = new Parse.ACL();
 acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
 acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);

 var roleName = user.get("email");

 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
 var companyRole = new Parse.Role(roleName, acl);
 console.log("Role = " + companyRole);
 companyRole.save();
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In Parse, you the name for a Role can only contains letters, numbers, and underscore. I was trying to set the role name as an email address, which contains '@' and '.'

I did a replace on these characters before I saved the name and worked perfectly. I wish Parse would've thrown an error if trying to save with invalid characters but problem solved now.

Comment: Did you check the cloud logs, because you should be getting errors. Your afterSave method should be throwing an error due to no success/error being called. You won't get errors client-side though.

Comment: Success was being called and this wasn't throwing any errors. I guess part doesn't validate string characters before calling success. Removing '.' from my role name was the key, makes sense now but annoying when not working and no errors to work with.